# JS Calculator variable prevKey doesn't register values properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

Still working on the JS Calculator for FreeCodeCamp. I've been working on this problem for the past few days. The problem is repeating operators. For example, if I press "5" then "+", but changed my mind and pressed "-". The history area should display "5-" instead of "5+".

After carefully studying what is wrong, I figured out how it's happening. If you check out my code at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/vWJxBW), you can see how the variable `prevKey` isn't gathering the numbers and operators in right order...

If I press in this order "5", "+", "-". The `prevKey` should be a number at first then an operator, and then an operator, or something like that. However, since I listed the variable `prevKey = null;`, it's been messing up the order. The prevkey actually goes like that: "5", "+", "null", "-".

How do I fix it?

Here's my code in question. All the actions are happening in `function addOperator(keyitem)`.

```
    subMatharray.push(mainMath);
    prevKey = mainMath;
    console.log("addOpKeyItem: " + keyitem);
    console.log("addOpPrevKey: " + prevKey);

    if(["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(prevKey) == -1) {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = keyitem;
      console.log("addOpArraySubArrayElse: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyElse: " + prevKey);
      console.log("addOpArrayoppArrayElse: " + oppArray);
      console.log("addOpArrayKeyItemElse: " + keyitem);
    } else if (["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(keyitem) > -1 && ["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(prevKey) > -1 || prevKey == null) {
      subMatharray.push("test");

      console.log("addOpArraySubArray: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKey: " + prevKey);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyItem: " + keyitem);
      console.log("addOpArrayoppArray: " + oppArray);
    }
```

And here's my full code here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = null;
  var subMath = "0";
  var finalset = "";
  var subMatharray = [];
  var oppArray = [];
  var equalPressed = false;
  var prevKey = null;
  var regexChecked = /[0-9]/g;
  var originalKey = "";
  update();
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    originalKey = keyitem;
    console.log("buttonpress: " + keyitem);
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case ".":
        addDecimal(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual(keyitem);
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = null;
     subMath = "0";
     prevKey = null;
     subMatharray = [];
     oppArray = [];
    if(mainMath == null){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "4em");
    }
    console.log("clearMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("clearSub: " + subMath);
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
    finalset = mainMath;
    console.log("plusminusMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("plusminusFinal: " + finalset);
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (mainMath === null){
      mainMath = "0";
    }
    if (mainMath == "0"){
      mainMath = keyitem/*mainMath.replace("0", keyitem);*/
      finalset = mainMath;
      return;
      console.log("addedMainZero: " + mainMath);
      console.log("addedFinalZero: " + finalset);
    }
    if (equalPressed == true){
      mainMath = keyitem;
      subMath = "0";
      subMatharray = [];
      equalPressed = false;
      console.log("addNumberEqualmain: " + mainMath);
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    finalset = mainMath;
    
    console.log("addedMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addedFinalset: " + finalset);
    console.log("addedarray: " + subMatharray);
    
    if(mainMath.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    if(mainMath === null && subMatharray.length === 0) { 
      return;
    }
    
    if (equalPressed == true){
      subMatharray = [];
      oppArray = [];
      equalPressed = false;
      console.log("addOpEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    }
    
    oppArray.push(keyitem);
    console.log("addOpArray: " + oppArray);
    var opkeyitem = "";
    
    subMatharray.push(mainMath);
    prevKey = mainMath;
    console.log("addOpKeyItem: " + keyitem);
    console.log("addOpPrevKey: " + prevKey);
    
    /*prevKey won't get numbers, only operators!!!!*/
    
    if(["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(prevKey) == -1) {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = keyitem;
      console.log("addOpArraySubArrayElse: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyElse: " + prevKey);
      console.log("addOpArrayoppArrayElse: " + oppArray);
      console.log("addOpArrayKeyItemElse: " + keyitem);
    } else if (["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(keyitem) > -1 && ["/", "*", "+", "-"].indexOf(prevKey) > -1 || prevKey == null) {
      oppArray.shift();
      opkeyitem = oppArray.toString();
      /*subMatharray.splice(-2, 2);
      /*subMatharray.pop();*/
      /*subMatharray.push(opkeyitem);*/
      subMatharray.push("test");
      /*oppArray = [];*/
      /*prevKey = null;*/
      console.log("addOpArraySubArray: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKey: " + prevKey);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyItem: " + keyitem);
      console.log("addOpArrayoppArray: " + oppArray);
    } /*else if(prevKey == null) {
      subMatharray.push(keyitem);
      prevKey = keyitem;
      console.log("addOpArraySubArrayElse: " + subMatharray);
      console.log("addOpArrayPrevKeyElse: " + prevKey);
      console.log("addOpArrayoppArrayElse: " + oppArray);
      console.log("addOpArrayKeyItemElse: " + keyitem);
    }*/
    
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = null;
    /*prevKey = null;*/
    console.log("addOpSub: " + subMath);
    console.log("addOpMain: " + mainMath);
    console.log("addOpMainarray: " + subMatharray);
    console.log("equaltrueTest: " + equalPressed);
  };
  
  function addDecimal(keyitem){
    if (mainMath === null){
      mainMath = "0";
    }
    if (mainMath.indexOf(keyitem) === -1){
      if(mainMath == "0") {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        return;
      }
    } else {
        return;
      }
    addNumber(keyitem);
  };
  
  function solveEqual(keyitem) {
    subMatharray.push(finalset);
    subMath = subMatharray.join("");
    mainMath = eval(subMath);
    console.log("solveEqualresult: " + mainMath);
    console.log("solveEqualhistory: " + subMath);
    console.log("solveEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
    var finalresult = mainMath.toString();
    if(finalresult.length > 8){
      $(".entry").css("font-size", "1.5em");
    }
    equalPressed = true;
  };
  
  function update(){
  $("#answer").html(mainMath === null ? "0" : mainMath);
  $("#history").html(subMath);
};
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 75px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 150px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty hard to follow. Eric Lippert has a great article to help you get started on [debugging small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). I think the answer will likely be in addOperand: before pushing the latest operand on your subMathArray, check if there already is an operand, and remove it.

```
function lastElement(array){
    return array[array.length - 1];
}

function isOperator(char){
    return '/*+-'.indexOf(char) >= 0;
}

function addOperator(keyitem){
  if(mainMath === null && subMatharray.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (equalPressed == true){
    subMatharray = [];
    oppArray = [];
    equalPressed = false;
    console.log("addOpEqualarray: " + subMatharray);
  }

  oppArray.push(keyitem);
  console.log("addOpArray: " + oppArray);
  var opkeyitem = "";

  const lastSubMath = lastElement(subMatharray);
  if(isOperator(lastSubMath)){
      subMatharray.pop();
  }

  subMatharray.push(mainMath);
  prevKey = mainMath;
  console.log("addOpKeyItem: " + keyitem);
  console.log("addOpPrevKey: " + prevKey);
  //etc
```

Since I was having a hard time following your code, I decided to refactor it. I used [eslint](https://eslint.org/) to automatically detect all the warnings that could easily be deleted. There was a lot. I then renamed your variables so they matched the UI elements to make it clearer. After I did this, it became clear that you don't need any array, and you don't need to remember previous key presses. All you need is 2 strings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let entry = '0'; // mainMath
  let history = null; // subMath
  update();

  $('button').click(function() {
    calculate($(this).attr('value'));
  });

  function calculate(keyitem) {
    switch (keyitem) {
      case 'clear':
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case '/':
      case '*':
      case '+':
      case '-':
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case 'plusminus':
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case '.':
        addDecimal();
        break;
      case '=':
        solveEqual();
        break;
    }
    update();
  };

  function clearScreen() {
    entry = '0';
    history = null;
  };

  function plusminusScreen() {
    entry = -1 * entry;
  };

  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (entry == '0') {
      entry = keyitem;
      history = keyitem;
      return;
    }

    if (isOperator(entry)) {
      entry = keyitem;
      history += keyitem;
      return;
    }

    entry += keyitem;
    history += keyitem;
  };

  function isOperator(char) {
    return '/*+-'.indexOf(char) >= 0;
  }

  function addOperator(keyitem) {
    if (history === null) {
      return;
    }

    if (isOperator(entry)) {
      // This part solves your repeating operator problem
      // If the current entry is an operator, replace the last
      // character in history with the new operator.
      history = history.substring(0, history.length - 1) + keyitem;
      entry = keyitem;
      return;
    }

    history += keyitem;
    entry = keyitem;
  };

  function addDecimal() {
    if (entry.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
      return;
    }

    entry += '.';
    if (history === null) {
      history = '0';
    }
    history += '.';
  };

  function solveEqual() {
    entry = eval(history);
    history = entry;
  };

  function update() {
    $('#answer').html(entry);
    $('#history').html(history);
  };
});
```

Comment: @KristinaBressler ? It's working fine from here. What's the problem?

Comment: @KristinaBressler is it not taking you to http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ?

Comment: It just took me to what looks like register.com page.

Comment: There's something really fishy going on here. You can use the actual url I just posted.

Comment: @KristinaBressler I think we just witnessed Eric's blog getting compromised live :O

Comment: @KristinaBressler Here's the wayback machine's archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20171113093102/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs

Comment: I did post relative code that I'm having problem with. The function addOperator first add the number and then the operator. However, what I do notice that it add a null in the array after I press another operator. This is the problem that I'm trying to figure out the past few days!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159180/discussion-between-guillaume-cr-and-kristina-bressler).

Comment: @KristinaBressler I found your bug. Please see edited answer.